# Upgrade to Ubuntu from Windows Vista

Tags: installation, wubi, windows-vista

I am trying to upgrade a Dell inspiron 1501 from Windows Vista to Ubuntu.  I downloaded the appropriate .ISO file from the Ubuntu site, and used Universal_USB-Installer to create a bootable USB.  However, when I run Wubi.exe and take the Help Me To Boot From CD option, I get the following:

```bsh
10-22 23:25 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Finished check_iso
10-22 23:25 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished use_cd
10-22 23:25 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running extract_kernel...
10-22 23:25 ERROR  TaskList: Could not retrieve the required installation files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 618, in extract_kernel
Exception: Could not retrieve the required installation files
10-22 23:25 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist
10-22 23:25 ERROR  root: Could not retrieve the required installation files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 58, in run
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 130, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 205, in run_cd_menu
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 122, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 228, in run_cd_boot
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 618, in extract_kernel
Exception: Could not retrieve the required installation files
10-22 23:25 DEBUG  TaskList: # Finished tasklist
```

Can you help please?

Thanks, Willie

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install with Wubi when it says "Could not retrieve the required disk image files"?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/254156/how-to-install-with-wubi-when-it-says-could-not-retrieve-the-required-disk-imag)

Answer (score 0):

you can try installing dual boot with windows if it will be suggested in install option . Also watch this manual https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m5Jxfj6tu_U

Comment: The reason I was getting off Vista is the machine has become incredibly slow, so I want to get rid of windows.  Where

Comment: @WillieHealy If you installing Ubuntu using Wubi, you won't be getting rid of Vista. Wubi will just be installed as a software on top of Windows. I wouldn't choose this solution if you are willing to get rid of Windows, I would just replace Windows altogether with Ubuntu. IMO, Wubi should be used as a demo/testing environment only, even though it runs well enough.