# Wubi install fails: Could not retrieve the required installation files

Tags: wubi

I have an old machine and the only way I can install Ubuntu is to use Wubi, but i get an error.

Here is the log: http://pastebin.com/a5YjaaKv

```
01-11 23:09 ERROR  CommonBackend: Invalid md5 for ISO C:\ubuntu\install\installation.iso (5d5d1a7da2a0659b163d4f8bd70fbe6f != 99594c45a0175a5570cdcc5c9cb3ed8f)
None
01-11 23:09 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Finished check_iso
01-11 23:09 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished use_cd
01-11 23:09 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running extract_kernel...
01-11 23:09 ERROR  TaskList: Could not retrieve the required installation files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 618, in extract_kernel
Exception: Could not retrieve the required installation files
```

Comment: i need to install ubuntu first so that then i can install xubuntu because on this laptop there is no way to boot from usb its a samsung q20

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install with Wubi when it says "Could not retrieve the required disk image files"?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/254156/how-to-install-with-wubi-when-it-says-could-not-retrieve-the-required-disk-imag)

Answer (score 2):

The CD in the `E:` drive is bad:

```
01-11 23:09 ERROR  CommonBackend: Invalid md5 for ISO C:\ubuntu\install\installation.iso 
(5d5d1a7da2a0659b163d4f8bd70fbe6f != 99594c45a0175a5570cdcc5c9cb3ed8f)
```

Run `wubi.exe` without the CD in the computer and it will download a new one, or if you have the ISO you used to create the CD, run `wubi.exe` in the same directory as the `ISO` (also making sure the CD is removed).

If that ISO is also bad, then run `wubi.exe` with no ISO or CD present and it will download a new ISO.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Ubuntu 13.04, the support for wubi was dropped, as you can see on the page [Windows install page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows):

> Windows installer is not compatible with Windows 8 or UEFI firmware, and is not available for Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue too mate, now I think it has been **fixed already** but something *else* may could've caused it too.

Recently I was trying to install Ubuntu when I found out that a .py source, called "pyrun" actually needs access to your firewall, now.. Ubuntu installation via a CD does not request this, may causing parts to be missing and unable to use in the installation which causes it to fail..

Try to use the CD - Startup Helper Installer, which asks for firewall permission for **pyrun**. After I did that, the installation completed.

You can also try to delete/eject the mounted image (make sure to have wubi.exe extracted to the desktop) And then run Wubi.

Hope this helps.