# Trying to launch from USB - "could not retrieve the required installation files"

Tags: usb, wubi

Let me just say I am totally new to Linux. I'm a basic Windows user.
I am trying to launch Ubuntu from a USB so I don't have to install on my laptop. 
I used pendrivelinux to save it my USB, and then launch it from there by clicking on "wubi". It then takes me to the demo/full install menu, I click on the "Help me to boot from CD", it loads and extracts the files but I get an error message after that says to view a log "appdata\local\temp\wubi-14.04-rev286.log"

Any information would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: Could you please paste the log onto www.paste.ubuntu.com and give me the link so someone can analyze the log.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install with Wubi when it says "Could not retrieve the required disk image files"?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/254156/how-to-install-with-wubi-when-it-says-could-not-retrieve-the-required-disk-imag)

Answer (score 0):

PLEASE READ THE LOG CAREFULLY....actually Wubi is trying to locate some particular file in ISO file (or any source like live-usb,etc) and when it could it gives this error...I too had this problem but after reading the log and comparing it with file in the ISO, I found vmlinuz was missing its file extension(in my case it ".efi"). Wubi was trying to locate "vmlinuz.efi" and it could find it as it was named as vmlinuz. I name renamed the file...every went well then suddenly I got another error and then again I studied the log,now it was a different error. Wubi tried to copy vmlinuz in my installation directory, which now was named as vmlinuz.efi, so I made a copied of "vmliunz.efi" file and renamed back to vmlinuz.

Eureka!! It was successful.

Steps to follow(this is strictly base on study of the log. I woould strongly recommend to read the log and verify every file Wubi is searching)

- files please go to your casper directory in your installation source
- make two copies of vmlinuz
- rename one of them to vmlinuz.efi and leave other as it is.

follow these steps and your are good to go.
If you still got issues please post the log-file too.

ivarbhardwaj